# Selecting a count of items and a count of all children for those items

Tags: sql, performance, aggregate

I am writing a query that reports on information about a location, including the total number of classes occurring at that location and the total number of attendees who are registered for those classes.  I need the results in a single row.

I am looking for the most efficient and/or most readable way to perform this query.

The cleanest query that I've come up with is the following:

```
SELECT Location.Id AS LocationId,
       --additional columns from location or joined tables...
       ClassStatistics.TotalClasses,
       ClassStatistics.TotalRegistrants
FROM Locations AS Location
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS TotalClasses,
            SUM(TotalRegistrantsInClass) AS TotalRegistrants
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                    Class.Id AS ClassId,
                    COUNT(*) AS TotalRegistrantsInClass
                FROM
                    Classes AS Class
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        Attendees AS Attendee
                    ON 
                        Attendee.ClassId = Class.Id
                WHERE
                    Class.LocationId= Location.Id
                GROUP BY
                    Class.Id
            ) AS AttendeeTotalsByClass
    ) AS ClassStatistics
WHERE
    Location.Id = 1
```

Is this sort of query acceptable in practice, or have I missed some magic to make it more efficient?

Comment: Is that query really works ? It returns two columns: columnClassId+TotalRegistrantsInClass from this inner query:  `SELECT Class.Id AS ClassId,  COUNT(*) AS TotalRegistrantsInClass  FROM`, but the outer query refers to NumberOfRegistrants in `COUNT(*) AS TotalClasses, SUM(NumberOfRegistrants) AS TotalRegistrants` ? This is an error, it cannot parse.

Comment: You're right, I had a typo in the outer apply.  That has been corrected in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You should just join directly to the Classes and Attendee tables. No need for all the sub-queries.

```
SELECT  Location.Id AS LocationId,
        --additional columns from location or joined tables...
        COUNT(DISTINCT C.ID) AS TotalClasses,
        COUNT(A.ID) AS TotalRegistrants
FROM    Locations AS L
INNER JOIN
        CLASSES C
ON      C.LocationId= L.Id      
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Attendees A
ON      A.ClassId = C.Id       
WHERE   L.Id = 1
GROUP BY
        Location.Id AS LocationId,
        --additional columns from location or joined tables...
```

Comment: This works, it's much cleaner, and it corrects a bug in the original that I didn't notice.  The original query that I posted was always yielding at one attendee for classes that had no attendees.  Didn't notice that before.  Thank you!

I'd like to up-vote your answer, but I don't have the reputation for that.  Gotta love being a SO newbie.